# I am using the python django, and i wanted to know to get use thingsboard dashboard, and database as postgresql

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, mqtt, thingsboard

I am using the Python3, Django and database as Postgresql, and I wanted to use the Thingsboard dashboard in my web application. can anyone pls guide me how can I use this

Comment: Asking for guides/tutorials is off topic for Stack Overflow. You need to try and do it yourself and when you get stuck ask a question including what you have and how it fails and somebody will probably help. Please read the doc about how to ask good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ThingsBoard has APIs which you can use. You may also customise it based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Go to THINGSBOARD_URL/swagger-ui.html get the list of all available REST APIs and use it as per your requirements. http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html